# Can Unity3D and Unreal Engine import some Corona projects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coronasdk, unreal-development-kit

I am a beginner in game development and met a problem. Please forgive my poor English if I say something wrong.
I have a Corona project which is a simple mini game. Now I want to develop a game in Unity3D or Unreal Engine. Is it possible that I can put the Corona mini game into the Unreal or Unity Project? I mean inserting the Corona mini game into an Unreal or Unity Project. Is there a example or a tutorial I can follow. I appreciate your help.

Comment: they are utterly unrelated, so NO.  note that this question is for **gamedev.com**.  (This site is only for questions about syntax errors, etc.)  Please click "delete" and go ahead and ask on gamedev.com.  You'll get many good answers straightaway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be migrated to http://gamedev.com.

Answer (score 0):

No they are two different things, it is like trying to open a door with the wrong key.